# Is it necessary to use lambda symbol in Common Lisp?

Tags: lambda, common-lisp, anonymous-function

I've been reading Paul Graham's ANSI Common Lisp recently, where he mentions

> In Common Lisp, you can express functions as lists, but they are represented internally as distinct function objects.  So lambda is no longer really necessary.

in chapter 2. However, if I omit the lambda symbol, I am unable to compile a correct program.

I try to calculate the Lisp function: `(((x) x) 1 )` instead of `((lambda (x) x) 1 )`, which should be same as the ANSI Common Lisp said. However, the code without lambda is unable to compile.

Comment: I think you must be taking that out of context. `LAMBDA` is definitely necessary.

Comment: if you write your own interpreter, anything's possible. some other Lisps might handle the kind of code you show. for instance, in AutoLISP, evaluating `( '((a)(+ a 1)) 0 )` returns `1`, as does evaluating `( (lambda (a)(+ a 1)) 0 )`.

Answer (score 5):

The full section from [chapter 2 of ACL](https://sep.turbifycdn.com/ty/cdn/paulgraham/acl2.txt?t=1688221954&), which is available on Paul Graham's [webpage about the book](https://paulgraham.com/acl.html).

> What is Lambda?
> The lambda in a lambda expression is not an operator.  It is just
> a symbol. [3]  In earlier dialects of Lisp it had a purpose:
> functions were represented internally as lists, and the only way
> to tell a function from an ordinary list was to check if the first
> element was the symbol lambda.
> In Common Lisp, you can express functions as lists, but they are
> represented internally as distinct function objects.  So lambda is
> no longer really necessary.  There would be no inconsistency in
> requiring that functions be denoted as

> ```
> ((x) (+ x 100))
> ```

> instead of

> ```
> (lambda (x) (+ x 100))
> ```

> but Lisp programmers were used to beginning functions with the
> symbol lambda, **so Common Lisp retained it for the sake of tradition.**

(Emphasis added).

He's speaking hypothetically here, about how the language *could* have had different syntax for defining functions instead of using `lambda` like it does. As Will mentioned in a comment, at least one other Lisp dialect does accept the `lambda`-less form. Common Lisp, however, requires it.

Answer (score 1):

Shawn's answer gets across what I think is Graham's point.

But it's worth noting that Graham is simply wrong about this

He's wrong because there is nothing to prevent a Lisp *which represents functions as lists* using a syntax like `((x y) x)` to denote a function, so long as it is a lisp-2.

So `lambda` is always a choice in such a Lisp.

If you want to allow the equivalent of `((lambda (...) ...) ...)` this is perfectly possible in such a Lisp: `((lambda (x y) x) 1 2)` becomes `(((x y) x) 1 2)` and note that this *can't* denote a function since the first element is not a valid lambda list: it must therefore be the application of an anonymous function.

However note in a Lisp-1, such a representation is *not* possible.  An expression like `((x y) x)` in such a lisp means: 'find the value of x which should be a function, call it with an argument which is the value of `y` and call the return value with an argument which is the value of `x`'.

So a Lisp-2 which wants not to be gratuitously incompatible with Lisp-1s should probably use `lambda` the way CL does.

---

As an example of how it is perfectly possible to have functions expressed in other ways in CL, here is how you might do that:

```
(defmacro fn (form)
  (etypecase form
    (symbol
     `(function ,form))
    (cons
     (let ((thing (first form)))
       (cond
        ((member thing '(lambda setf))
         `(function ,form))
        ((and (listp thing)
              (or (null thing)
                  (symbolp (first thing))))
         `(function (lambda ,thing ,@(rest form)))))))))

(defun read-function-form (stream char prefix)
  (declare (ignore char prefix))
  `(fn ,(read stream)))

(set-dispatch-macro-character 
 #\# #\'
 #'read-function-form)
```

And now

```
> (funcall #'((x) x) 1)
1
```

Answer (score 1):

***Lambda expressions* in the Common Lisp standard**

The Common Lisp standard has a glossary entry [lambda expression](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_l.htm#lambda_expression):

> **lambda expression** *n.* a list which can be used in place of a function name in certain contexts to denote a function by directly describing its behavior rather than indirectly by referring to the name of an established function; its name derives from the fact that its first element is the symbol `lambda`.

There are no ways to denote such a function without using a `lambda` symbol.

The *lambda expressio*n syntax is also documented. See for example here: [lambda](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_lambda.htm).

This is the *EBNF* syntax for *lambda expressions*:

> `lambda` *lambda-list* [[*declaration** | *documentation*]] *form**

An example would be:

```
(lambda (a &optional (b 1))
  (declare (type number a b))
  "Increments the value of a by b"
  (+ a b))
```

**Where can I use these *lambda expressions*?**

*Lambda expressions* are used in two places in the language:

- Inside `function` forms: `(function (lambda (x) (1+ x)))`, which can also be written as `#'(lambda (x) (1+ x))`.
- There is also a hardwired Common Lisp syntax to call them directly `((lambda (x) (1+ x)) 41)`. Here the *lambda expression* `(lambda (x) (1+ x))` is called with the argument `41`.